# JavaScript - Firebase Realtime Database waits too long in case of network error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Any time I want to make a request to the database using client-side JavaScript, whether it's a read using `ref.once()`, a set, or a remove, if I simulate a network loss and then run the behavior that makes the database request, Firebase will wait forever, continually trying to make the connection.

```js
database.ref(`resources/${id}`).set(res).then(() => {
    // handle successful read
}).catch((error) => {
    // handle problem
});
```

In this case I would have expected Firebase to reject the promise after a certain amount of time, resulting in the catch callback, but with a network error, neither the successful or unsuccessful callbacks are called and I'm stuck without any callbacks.

Does Firebase provide a way to set a timeout? If not, I'm thinking I can build my own timeout using `Promise.race()` but I was hoping for a simpler solution.